# Async requests priority

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I'm using angularJS and i'm sending two types of requests, one directly on the ng-src to retreive an image from my backend and the other type is 4 async requests to prefetch images in client cache.

What i want to do is that the ng-src request always get the priority even if there's pending async requests . is that possible ?

- 1 ng-src Request
- 2-6 Aync requests to prefetch images (pending...)
- 7
  another ng-src Request

but this last request i want to shuffle its priority over the async requests to get something like

1-->7--->2-6

**EDIT :**

I have a panel where i display an Image from my backend, what i want to do is prefetching the next four images in background each time an image is shown so the user gets the image from the cache each time. I have already implemented that, my problem is when i try to display the next image even if its in the cache, the browser dosent respond when it has several prefetching requests pending.

so what i want to do is a sort of two queues, one for the ng-src request (actual image in the panel) and another one for prefetching images in background,it's an idea but i would be interested to know how this can be implemented without changing anything on the server side.

Comment: Nope. Once you've sent the request, the browser does nothing but wait for the response. If you want any kind of priority *after* the requests have been sent, you'll have to do it on the server.

Comment: You could possibly write code to keep track of the number of outstanding `ng-src` requests, and write code into the client-side response handlers for 2-6 to wait to do their operations until the number of outstanding `ng-src` requests is zero.

Comment: Like @Juhana said this is not something you can do and trying to do it on the server would not be fun. The question here is what are you really trying to do? Is this an issue of order of operation where you need the results of 1 and 7 to correctly handle the results of 2-6?

Comment: @MichaelHobbs  I have updated my post, explaining what i  want to implement